# MySQL PHP insert into datatime

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update some data in my DB via:

```
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE `booking` SET status = ?, datecreated = ? WHERE day = ? AND timeSlot = ?")){
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', 'processing', 'now()', $results[0]['timeSlot'], $results[0]['day']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo 'Updated';
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

The column `datecreated` is a datetime type.

I have tried now() and 'now()' and date('Y-m-d H:i:s') all 3 give me the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind *variables* that can be referenced.  If they aren't *variables* then put them directly in the query:

```
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE `booking` SET status = 'processing', datecreated = NOW() WHERE day = ? AND timeSlot = ?")){
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $results[0]['timeSlot'], $results[0]['day']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo 'Updated';
}
```

Or I guess you could do `$booking = 'processing';` and `$datecreated = 'NOW()';` and binds those variables if you must.